# How to change the Languages value shown under the Information section for my app in App Store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have implemented an iOS application and published in App Store as well. In my iTunes account, I have specifically mentioned that my primary language is Swedish.

[image]

In my test device I set my region as India and Language as Hindi. Also I have changed my region for India in my Apple account. But when I load the App Store application, searched and view my application, under Information category, Languages value display as "English".

[image]
[image]

How that is possible and how can I change it to Swedish (Svenska) language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Xcode's localisation functionality to provide languages for your app.

> The list of languages displayed in the store under Languages is set in the app build.

<sup>[Displaying on the Store in More Than One Language (Optional) - iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html)</sup>

If you don't use Xcode's localisation, you'll have to set the languages manually by adding them to the CFBundleLocalizations array in your Info.plist.

> CFBundleLocalizations (Array - iOS, macOS) identifies the localizations handled manually by your app. If your executable is unbundled or does not use the existing bundle localization mechanism, you can include this key to specify the localizations your app does handle.

<sup>[Core Foundation Keys - Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-109552-TPXREF111)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I did the change. I believe that I'll be able to see the change after uploading a new build to iTuens connect?

Comment: @AnujAroshA Yes, once the new build is ready for sale, the languages in that build will be shown.